# Basic Gaussian Function Plot

Tags: plotting

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to plot a Gaussian function (actually a sum of three Gaussian functions) using custom x-axis tick marks.

Here's what I have so far:

```
a0 = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BohrRadius"]]];
c1 = 0.154329;
c2 = 0.535328;
c3 = 0.444635;
a1 = 2.227660;
a2 = 0.405771;
a3 = 0.109818;
z1 = (2 * a1 / pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a1 * (x / a0)^2];
z2 = (2 * a2 / pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a2 * (x / a0)^2];
z3 = (2 * a3 / pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a3 * (x / a0)^2];
Plot[y = a0^(-3/2) * (c1 * z1 + c2 * z2 + c3 * z3),
 PlotRange -> {{-15a0, 15a0}}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{k a0, Style[If[k > 1, Row[{k, Subscript[a, 0]}], Subscript[a, 0]],
                              Small]},
                 {k, -15, 15}], Automatic}]
```

I'm getting a really basic error (Plot::argr: Plot called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.), but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

EDIT: Thanks to Alexei Boulbitch, here's my final code after edits.

```
a0 = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BohrRadius"]]];
Subscript[c, 1] = 0.154329;
Subscript[c, 2] = 0.535328;
Subscript[c, 3] = 0.444635;
a1 = 2.227660;
a2 = 0.405771;
a3 = 0.109818;
Subscript[\[Phi], 1] = (2*a1/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a1*(x/a0)^2];
Subscript[\[Phi], 2] = (2*a2/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a2*(x/a0)^2];
Subscript[\[Phi], 3] = (2*a3/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a3*(x/a0)^2];
Subscript[\[Psi], 1s] = a0^(-3/2)*(Subscript[c, 1] * Subscript[\[Phi], 1] + 
                          Subscript[c, 2] * Subscript[\[Phi], 2] + 
                          Subscript[c, 3] * Subscript[\[Phi], 3]);
Subscript[\[Psi], 1sActual] = a0^(-3/2) / Sqrt[Pi] * Exp[-x/a0];
str = ToString[Subscript["\[Psi]", "1s"], StandardForm];
Plot[{Subscript[\[Psi], 1s], Subscript[\[Psi], 1sActual]}, {x, 0, 7a0}, 
PlotLegends-> "Expressions",
Ticks -> {Table[{k a0, Style[If[k > -8, Row[{k, Subscript[a, 0]}], 
Subscript[a, 0]],
                          Small]},
             {k, 0, 7}], Automatic}]
Plot[{Subscript[\[Phi], 1], Subscript[\[Phi], 2], Subscript[\[Phi], 3], 
  (Subscript[c, 1] * Subscript[\[Phi], 1] + Subscript[c, 2] * 
Subscript[\[Phi], 2] + 
   Subscript[c, 3] * Subscript[\[Phi], 3])}, {x, -7a0, 7a0}, 
PlotRange -> {{-7a0, 7a0}, {0, 1.35}},
PlotLegends-> "Expressions",
Ticks -> {Table[{k a0, Style[If[k > -8, Row[{k, Subscript[a, 0]}], Subscript[a, 0]],
                          Small]},
             {k, -7, 7}], Automatic}]
```

Comment: You did not specify the range of `Plot`'s argument (presumably `x`); the option `PlotRange` serves a different purpose, check the documentation, you do not need to use the assignment operator inside plot (just specify the expression you want to plot), defining functions the way you did is generally bad practice (`z1[x_] = ...` would be better, so that `x` is explicitly an argument of `Plot`. Read the error message! You supplied plot with 1 argument -- the expression, you didn't give the 2nd argument: the variable and its limits. VTC as "simple mistake".

Comment: ...as "simple mistake", but realistically, consult the documentation to find out the proper syntax of `Plot`. Try it with a simpler example first.

Comment: Oh yeah, `pi` is undefined. Mathematica's symbol names are case-sensitive, you're looking for the built-in `Pi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that you start from this:

```
a0 = 1;
c1 = 0.154329;
c2 = 0.535328;
c3 = 0.444635;
a1 = 2.227660;
a2 = 0.405771;
a3 = 0.109818;
z1 = (2*a1/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a1*(x/a0)^2];
z2 = (2*a2/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a2*(x/a0)^2];
z3 = (2*a3/Pi)^(3/4) Exp[-a3*(x/a0)^2];
Plot[a0^(-3/2)*(c1*z1 + c2*z2 + c3*z3), {x, -1, 1}]
```

which gives the answer:

[image]

and then one-by-one add your options and change the definitions. Then you will see what's wrong. One tip: this `a0 = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "BohrRadius"]]]` creates a part of your troubles.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much! I went back and did what you said, switching one thing after another and I managed to get the exact graph I wanted. Thank you again!